# Share single database connection between two micro-services

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, microservices

I have two micro-services written using .net core that shares a single database (sql server) i want to unify database connection between the two micro-services is this possible to do ?

Comment: You can use same connection string for both microservices. In this case both microservices will connect to the same database instance.

Comment: Why would you want to? Databases are designed to handle lots of connections. You don't even want to share a single connection around one of your microservices. But to answer your question, yes it is possible, create a third microservice that connects to the database and pass queries from your two microservices to the third one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.Net and database server instance manage Actual(physical) database connections. Every time applications request to open a connection to the database; it is provided from a connection pool. And, when a connection is closed in an application, it is returned to the pool. 
You may able to share the connection object by some of the inter-process-communication methods and native coding, but it is not a good pattern. 

If you need a connection for keeping a transaction in both services, it is better to do that by using distributed transactions.

Comment: that is what i want the two micro-services using the same object that is responsible of connecting to database

Comment: So, I think you can create an additional layer (service) to act as a database access layer here. Those two micro-services can use this service to access to the database. Is it possible?

Comment: i found this stuff here https://www.codemag.com/Article/0301091/Remote-Object-Models-In-.NET i think this is can be useful dont you ?

Comment: Only if connection classes such as the SqlConnection is inherited from MarshalByRefObject. Otherwise, you can not access them from another process. Please consider using a third micro-service as a data access layer.